# Determine the formula of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinations

Given the sequence:
\begin{align}
p_0&=1\\
p_1&= \dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\\
p_2&= \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\left(\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}+1\right)\\
p_3&= \dfrac{1}{6}\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\left(\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}+1\right)\left(\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}+2\right)\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
for $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$. Determine the formula for given sequence above.

I determine the formula by
$$p_n=C\left({\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+n-1},{n}\right)$$
for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$.

Now I doubt with my answer because $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ is real number so usually we can't write it into combination notation.

May we write the sequence formula as above? Or can we write it into gamma function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without making things more complicated than need be (i.e. having seen the first few terms can never determine an infinite sequence), the intended answer might be simply
$$p_n=\frac1{n!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+k \right) \qquad \text{for} \quad n \geq 1$$
with $p_0 \equiv 1$ just as a definition.

One can view $p_0$ as being part of the formula with the interpretation that "number of the terms in the product is $n$". Here $n=0$ means no product, in other words, "not multiplying anything to the existing stuff". Not multiplying anything is the same as multiplying by $1$.